# Replace special character if between any two characters in SQL

Tags: php, sql, regex

I am making a SQL call via PHP to get the following sample data:

`Item 1: Blaster-Blue,Item 2: Blaster-Red, Extended Mag,Item 3: Kit-Thermal Det, 2" Spanner, Motivator`

I want to replace any comma that has characters surrounding it with the characters `||` while ignore commas that are preceded/followed by white-space.

So my expected output would be:

`Item 1: Blaster-Blue || Item 2: Blaster-Red, Extended Mag || Item 3: Kit-Thermal Det, 2" Spanner, Motivator`

And then store it back in the SQL table.

**What I've tried:**

I know that in JavaScript you could do it like this:

```js
const str = `Item 1: Blaster-Blue,Item 2: Blaster-Red, Extended Mag,Item 3: Kit-Thermal Det, 2" Spanner, Motivator`;
console.log(
  str.replace(/.(?<=\w\,)(?=\w+)/g, ' || ')
);
```

But I could not find any resources on how to convert this into a SQL statement. I gave it my best shot with what I could find but it just isn't working for me so far.

> $sql = "UPDATE myTable SET description = REPLACE(".call_method(new
>   RegExp(".(?<=\w\,)(?=\w+)", "g"), " || ");

Comment: Regexp support differs greatly in different DBMSes.

Comment: Do you need to solve this with a single SQL call? Or can you use PHP regular expressions to edit the value before re-insertion?

Comment: I think we need a single call, as this would affect all data in my Table. But someone with more knowledge my know a better way. @serg I do realize they are different but there must be a way to replace commas that are surrounded by text in SQL (I feel I'm making it harder than it should be), so it doesn't have to be regex, it could be a comparable SQL function.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible, I'd use PHP to edit the string before re-insertion. I'm not sure how you're getting the data, but you could select all the erroneous texts with an initial SQL query. In a loop over the result, you could process all entries like this:

```
$dirty_sample = `Item 1: Blaster-Blue,Item 2: Blaster-Red, Extended Mag,Item 3: Kit-Thermal Det, 2" Spanner, Motivator`

$re = '/\S,\S/gm'; // the regular expression selecting a comma enclosed by non-whitespaces
$str = 'Item 1: Blaster-Blue,Item 2: Blaster-Red, Extended Mag,Item 3: Kit-Thermal Det, 2" Spanner, Motivator';
$subst = ' || ';

$clean_result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Depending on how you are getting the original string, you can use the ID

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE mytable SET description = ? where id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $clean_result , $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

or use the original string match to update:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE mytable SET description = ? where description = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $clean_result , $dirty_sample);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is a great resource to fiddle with regexes (preloaded with the example above) https://regex101.com/r/j7MPPF/1